# what is the win32 alternative to the Unix daemon() subroutine?

Tags: c, winapi, daemon

I have to call several (> 10) .exe command line programs in the background.
Creating a Windows Services doesn't sound very appealling in this context - c'mon, that's a bit overpowered for such a simple task.

Is there anything like a [daemon(3)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=daemon&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE&format=html) subroutine for Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look into using the [**srvany.exe**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) service wrapper found in the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd).  I have used this method quite successfully under Windows XP, but I cannot comment on how it may work for newer versions of the OS.

There seems to be [plenty of information available<sup>1</sup>](http://www.google.com/search?q=srvany+howto) on how to use this tool.

<sub>1 - Google search for srvany+howto</sub>